# How to Exit a While loop containing a switch - Java

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

This is for an assignment for a computers class. This is going beyond what the teacher asked for, so I am not asking you people to do my school work for me. What I am not able to understand is how to exit the switch and the while. I know that using *break;* will exit the while loop, and using *break;* will exit a switch. What I am looking for is some code that will exit a switch and a while loop at the same time. What I could do is just use

```
if (upgrade == 1){
    // Do Stuff
}

if (upgrade == 2){
    // Do Stuff
}

if (upgrade == 3){
    // Do Stuff
}

if (upgrade == 4){
    // Do Stuff
}

if (upgrade == 0){
    break;    // Exit the while loop
}
```

However, the teacher does not want us to use that format, but instead use switches. I also thought that I could just add the

```
if (upgrade == 0){
    Break;
}
```

To the bottom, but that still is not using a switch, and my teacher would not be happy with it. Is there any way to exit a swtich and a while loop at the same time?

This is what he wants the code to look like:

```
while (timesLeveled > 0){

    System.out.println("Upgrade Stats");

    upgrade = chooseUpgrade();    // retrieves the number for upgrade

    switch (upgrade){
    case 1: 
        // Do stuff if upgrade is 1
        break;


    case 2:
                    // Do stuff if upgrade is 2
        break;


    case 3: 
        // Do stuff if upgrade is 3
        break;

    case 4:
        // Do stuff if upgrade is 4
        break;


    case 0:

        break;

    }   // Closes off Switch

            timesLeveled--; // resets level counter

        }   // Closes off while (timesLeveled)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would usually recommend against using a `switch` at all when you have the option, but if you have to stick with it, you probably want the [`break` with label](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

```
WhileLoop: while (timesLeveled > 0) {
    ...
    case n:
        // do stuff
        break WhileLoop;
    ...
}
```

Note that this usage usually means that your code needs more than one significant cleanup (Replace Conditional with Polymorphism, loop improvement, etc.).

Comment: Why do you recommend against `switch`?

Comment: As an alternative: if the `while` loop is in its own method (and the code following the loop are not), then you can use `return` instead of `break`.

Comment: @nhgrif `switch` statements have clumsy syntax that make errors easy, they frequently use data types (like `char`) where only a few of the legal values are handled, and they spread out the behavior associated with values all over the code. An enum, by contrast, has clearly-defined legal values, and interesting behavior can be added to them using polymorphism instead of explicit flow control (and they can implement interfaces for even more flexibility).

Comment: So you recommend against `switch` in this case, but would be fine with it if he were using an `enum`?

Comment: @nhgrif Since the return value of `chooseUpgrade()` is a magic `int` that stands for some particular upgrade selection, this is a perfect example of when to use an enum. Even if it made sense structurally to retain the `switch`, it's a lot easier to understand `ATTACK_SPEED` and `DAMAGE` than `1` and `3` (and less error-prone).

Comment: @chrylis i wish I could have used that in this project, but our teacher is strict, and only wants us to use way he's taught us.

Comment: @Jordan.McBride I understand the limitations you have in school assignments; I wanted to make you aware of better options for code you write in the future.

Comment: what is this "WhileLoop: while" magic? I've never seen this before - is this common practice?

Comment: @Jona It's a label, and it's not common.